# Analyze the continuity of $f(x, y) = \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor y\rfloor$ and $f(x, y) = \lfloor x + y\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I think that this functions may have discontinuties at integer values.

Comment: You are definitely right.

Comment: Ah, but integer values of what?!? There's the rub.....

Answer (score 2):

The first function is continuous at $\Bbb R^2\setminus((\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z)\cup(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb R))$.

The second one at $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x+y\notin \Bbb Z\}$.

For a proof, consider a point at the guessed set of continuity. They are open sets, so take a neighbourhood of that point. At that neighbourhood the function is constant. Now we must show that the functions are not continuous at any point of the complement. Again take a point and a connected neighbourhood (an open ball, for example). The image of the function in that neighbourhood is a set with more than one integer. This shows discontinuity, since the image of some connected set is not connected.